# Get amount of reserved memory from an array

Tags: c++

Consider the following case:

```
int MyClass::MyMethod(char *myChar)
```

Am I able to get the amount of reserved space by `myChar` within memory (heap and stack) ? For example, if `myChar` points to the first element of an array called `char myArray[10]`: By use of `myChar`, can I get the amount of `char` that can be stored within `myArray`?

Comment: why do you need it? Sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It cannot be done in standard c++ btw

Comment: I need to find memory leaks caused by an Trim Method. Its important whether a string has a size, of x, or it has a size of 0 , while the array reserves space for 10 chars.

Comment: Strangely closely realted it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109114/avoiding-the-funcchar-api-on-embedded/65178718#65178718

Comment: I don't really get it. Why don't you just reproduce the memory leak by passing in an array of the size you need to do so? Then you'll already know what the size is... If the function breaks when you pass some other size, then pass _that_ size and debug/fix the problem.

Comment: Did you mean to use `string_view` or `span`?

Answer (score 0):

> By use of myChar, can I get the amount of char that can be stored within myArray?

In general no, there is no way to get the size of an array from just knowing a pointer to (first) element of that array.

If you know something special about the contents of the array, then it may be possible. For example, it is quite common for character strings to be in a null terminated array where the null character is the last element of the array In such case, you can count the number of elements until you reach the terminator. There are standard functions for this purpose.

Comment: When a string has "\0" at its end, I can use strlen(). My intention was to discover the space that was reserved.

Comment: @chhu In that case, read the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: However, if the space is indeed "reserved" (i.e. no "string" has been put there yet) it's likely that `strlen` isn't going to reliably help